# Android app crashing when starting service that uses LocationListener, any ideas?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, service

I'm struggling to understand why this application is crashing, when I add the request for location updates.

I have in my activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        startService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));
    }
```

And the code for my service is as follows:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LocationService extends Service {
    public LocationManager locationManager;
    public MyLocationListener listener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        listener = new MyLocationListener();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 4000, 0, listener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 4000, 0, listener);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
    }

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        public void onLocationChanged(final Location loc) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Location - Lat: " + String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude())
                 + "; Lon: " + String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

    }
}
```

At the minute, I just want to get a toast working. Later I plan to return the data to the activity via a broadcast, but can't get my head around why this toast isn't working.

If I comment out the code in onStart and replace it with a toast then the toast is displayed.

Does anyone have an idea as to why it isn't working?

I've registered the service in *AndroidManifest.xml*

```
    <service
        android:name=".LocationService">
    </service>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the log? And you don't need to request location updates using both providers, just one. I would look into FusedLocationProvider

Comment: Check if you need to add Nework permission. If you post th error log if would be great..

Comment: How do I obtain an error log? It's something I have never done. I am using Android Studio. Thanks